# Replace string in a file object and not the file itself

Tags: java, scala

I have a file that I'm reading from a Scala program like this:

```
val batchFile = new File(this.getClass.getResource("/batch.yaml").toURI)
```

The `batch.yaml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: deployer
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: deployer-pod
          image: sparker0i/deployer-pod:timemillis
          command: ["/opt/app/bin/start", $$TEST]
```

Now I need to replace the `$$TEST` with the value I generate from within the code.
The problem is I don't want to write it back to the File itself because this file will be used multiple times during the same program run. I want to somehow replace `$$TEST` inside the variable `batchFile` itself.

This is because the next step is to pass this to my next function which will call my Openshift cluter API.. This function has two signatures - one that can accept a `File` and the other that can accept an `InputStream`.

So is there a way I can replace a string inside a `File` or an `InputStream` without actually writing to the file, while being able to pass the `File` or `InputStream` object to my next function?

Comment: Yes, you can read the file contents into memory, do the string replacement and then create an inputstream that just returns that string.

Comment: If the content of the file is small (as in your example), just go with Strings or optionally InputStream if you really have to.

Comment: @GaëlJ this was just a sample, the YAML is even bigger than this. My problem is that the next function that I call (which comes from a library) needs either a `File` or an `InputStream`, which has to contain the substituted content.

Comment: The question is whether the file is "bigger than this" or "big" - e.g. if the file is 10GB large it is infeasible to hold in memory, if the file is just "bigger than this" implying even a few MB this should not be a problem.

Comment: Just somewhat bigger than this, won't go beyond 2MB, but can have 10000 lines..